# Django SelectMultiply widjet: how to set initial values to set as "selected"

Tags: django, forms

In **init** method of my ModelForm, I set type of field:

```python
self.fields['gwlist'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='List of gateways:',
    queryset=Gateway.objects.all(),
    initial={'gwlist': initial_list})
```

I want to set some gateways selected in whole gateway list, when form is showing for user. But I can't.

Does it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `initial` as a list of selected gateways (not a dict).  For example:

```
initial_list = [Gateway.objects.get(pk=1)]

self.fields['gwlist'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                            label='List of gateways:',
                                            queryset=Gateway.objects.all(),
                                            initial=initial_list)
```

**UPDATE**: If you define `gwlist` field at the `Form` level then you should set the `initial` in the form's `__init__()` constructor:

```
class DPForm(ModelForm):

    gwlist = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='List of gateways:',
                                            queryset=Gateway.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DPForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        init_list = [Gateway.objects.get(pk=11)]
        self.fields['gwlist'].initial=init_list
```

Comment: Thank you, catavaran. I tried to use list, tuple and dict. But, my <options> doesn't have "selected" parameter.

Comment: I checked this exact code - it works fine.  Show your code with a list `initial`, please.

Comment: The code at pastebin is different from the code in your question.  See the updated answer.

Comment: I agreed, @catavaran, about __init__ method. I put [http://pastebin.com/TefbegB5] new version of form-class. Still have no success. I know, your advice is correct, but my <select> still have no "selected". Maybe, I have wrong other stuff.

Comment: I copied and tested your code and it worked without any problem.  Restart your server and reload the page again.  Note that then you test the `initial` values you shouldn't use the "Refresh" button in the browser to reload the page. Press `Ctrl-L` and then `Enter`.

Comment: Misterious behaviour, BUT still this list: <select id="id_gwlist" class="form-control" name="gwlist" multiple="multiple">
<option value="11">GW1</option>
<option value="12">GW2</option>
<option value="14">GW3</option>

Comment: Show the code of your view.  What happens then you pass just `{'form': DialpeerForm()}` to the `render()` call?

Answer (score 0):

Working version of form (for me):

```python
class DialpeerForm(ModelForm):
    gwlist = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Список гейтвеев:',
            queryset=Gateway.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DialpeerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        init_list = [Gateway.objects.all()]
        self.initial['gwlist'] = init_list
```

I read before, that update initial value for field is not work. So, we need update initial for hole form. And magic bullet in this string:
**self.initial['gwlist'] = init_list**

Now  which I need have "selected" param.

*Django 1.7.5*